# Micro SD Card dead after formatting

Tags: sd-card

I was trying to format a brand new Micro SD Card using https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/, however, after 30 minutes, it failed. Every attempt thereafter also failed with this message;

```
[ERROR] Invalid end of sector signature: 0x2211
[ERROR] fat_check_validate_boot_sector returned error: 22 (Invalid argument)
[ERROR] Initializing cached values failed: 22 (Invalid argument)
[ERROR] Generated invalid volume. fat_volume_create returned: 22 (Invalid argument)
```

This happened on 2 brand new SD cards. The very first time they show up, after trying to format them, they seem completely dead.

Disk Utility also fails to do anything with the SD cards. I've tried to format them on a Windows machine, but they don't show up at all there.

I'm completely lost on what to do at the moment. I'm afraid that if I go out and buy another new SD card, the same problem will just happen again.

I'm using a 2016 MacBook Pro, with sd card -> USB -> thunderbolt.

Comment: Why didn't you use Disk Utility to begin with? I've never needed to use a 3rd party app to format any SD card. Ever.

Comment: Test with the Fight Flash Fraud app [F3X](https://github.com/insidegui/F3X)

Comment: @Tetsujin Sadly the application doesn't seem to start on my version of MacOS.

Comment: Dammit, no it doesn't any more. I don't know of any alternative.